# Eclipse does not create new apk after a file has been modified and saved

Tags: android, eclipse, build

I am working on android programs using Eclipse.  After I change something in any java file (any project file) when I click run button, Eclipse asks "save changes?".  Once I click Yes, the file gets saved. But eclipse does not create a new build (apk file).  A warning appears on the console "Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front" and device runs the app. In order to create a new apk I need to clean the project every time.  During the debugging phases, those steps add unwanted delay (and more clicks)

Expectation is when there is a file change, eclipse should create a new apk and load it.  In my case it is not happening.  Where should I make changes to behave it like that? (I hope it is a simple click somewhere, not create a make file etc..)

Comment: "Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front"- this warning comes when your app is not closed in Emulator or Device. close the app and run the program..

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse under Project menu click Project->Build Automatically

If that is already ticked - try starting eclipse with the -clean flag i.e go to your shortcut to eclipse and simple add -clean after eclipse.exe or eclipse

The reason it is saying the message about the activity being brought to the front is that the version adb is installing is the same as the one installed - so it just reuses it, and that is because Eclipse is not auotmatically building your APK.